# Count all the letters (26) of one of the char variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a dataframe with a few columns like this:

```
Attr    Description
60      asdfg asdg dfs
50      smlefekl dewld ewf
35      kojewdfhef e
```

All I need is to create extra 26 columns with counts of each letter in a row. I know I can use:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(mydata, ""), use.names=FALSE))
```

for a vector, but how can I update it for a dataframe?

Comment: Try `lapply(letters, function(x) str_count(dat$col, x))`

Comment: Thanks, akrun, but it just gives me a list of vectors with zeros

Comment: If you check the solution below, it is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using the `strsplit`, then we may need to create a `factor` with `levels` specified as 'letters'

```
d1 <- stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$Description, ""), seq_len(nrow(df1))))
d2 <- subset(d1, values != " ")
d2$values <- factor(d2$values, levels = letters)
t(table(d2))
#   values
# ind a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z    
#  1 2 0 0 3 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  2 0 0 0 2 4 2 0 0 0 0 1 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 1 3 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

---

Or as showed in the comments, use the `str_count` from `stringr` by looping through the 'letters' get the count of that letter for each row of 'Description'

```
library(stringr)
t(sapply(letters, function(x) str_count(df1$Description, x)))
```

Comment: Thanks again, but now I get a matrix of 26 xrows with all zeroes..?

Comment: @VR6 Based on the data u showed, I am not getting `all 0's`

Comment: I made up the Description column due to security reasons. All the characters were upper case, so I used the tolower function and I get something :)

Comment: @VR6 okay, then you may need to convert to lower or upper characerts or use `ignore.case`

Comment: The short solution worked as a charm, thanks a lot, akrun!